# NetworkManager wireless connection fails to connect

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, systemd, networkmanager

I am trying to get wireless networking using my laptop's [Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205](http://ark.intel.com/products/59471/Intel-Centrino-Advanced-N-6205-Dual-Band?q=Intel%20Centrino%20Advanced-N%206205) under *Arch Linux*. While I am able to scan for and see wireless signals with `nmcli dev wifi list` as well as `nmtui`, I can't seem to connect.

`nmtui` produces:

[image: Could not activate connection: Activation failed]

This happens whether the network I am trying to connect to has `WPA2` encryption or is unencrypted.

`systemctl --type=service` shows that this service is running:

> NetworkManager.service

Can you provide any guidance on how I can resolve this issue and get wifi working? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I uninstalled `netctl` and `connman` and restarted my computer, whereby `systemd-networkd.service` disappeared. Wireless still doesn't work, but atleast I can rule out conflicting services. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the result of `{ lspci ; lsusb ; } | grep -i wireless`

Comment: Connect manually, as per [the wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wifi), and you will be able to pinpoint exactly where your connection is failing...

Comment: @agc While searching for wireless doesn't return any matches, lspci turns up that the wireless hardware is Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205.

Answer (score 1):

Is installing and setting up `wicd` out of the question?  I've used `network-manager` on various laptops with various wifi cards and dongles, and sometimes `network-manager` works fine... but when it fails, it doesn't give much information as to what might be wrong, sometimes its errors omit some necessary piece of debugging data, other times the messages are vague.

As a "*Plan **B***", `wicd` is not perfect, but for some problems its GUI is easier to configure, its wifi network chooser shows more info, and it often *just works* when `network-manager` does not.

Bonus:  On *Debian* based systems the two wifi-managers can co-exist.  Uninstalling is not required.

Comment: Suggesting another tool is relying more on hope than science; connecting manually is the only sensible approach to debug this tyoe of issue.

Comment: @jasonwryan, that's correct *if* the OP's wifi troubles are due to a hardware driver problem, or some lower level wireless toolchain config setting.   Incorrect if the problem is in the code of `network-manager` itself .

Comment: If it was an issue with network-manager, there would be *a lot* more people screaming about it...

Comment: @jasonwryan, not if it's a subtle Front-end bug that's only triggered by certain cheaper hardware setups.  Further biases: those most affected wouldn't *be* online to complain; once they somehow get online they might be too weary to care enough to complain; and expert Linux network coders might prefer Atheros hardware so they'd never be affected.

Comment: @agc I'm keen on taking a cli friendly approach, so wicd is not really an option for me.